# XPath in a logic app to extract a value based on its type

Tags: xml, xpath, azure-logic-apps

I am using a logic app to dissect and reconstruct an inbound XML. The problem that I am having is that a portion of the XML is not always in the same order with the same amount of subsections. So I am wondering if it was possible to return the value based on the type? I.e in this example I want to return the value 2 where 2 is not always the second context.

```
 <ContextCollection>
  <Context>
    <Type>test1</Type>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </Context>
  <Context>
    <Type>test2</Type>
    <Value>2</Value>
  </Context>
  <Context>
    <Type>test3</Type>
    <Value>3</Value>
  </Context>
```

I have successfully used the following expression `xpath(xml(variables('XMLStripNameSpace')),'string(/*[name()="ContextCollection"]/*[name()="Context"][2]/*[name()="Value"])')`

but this obviously does not work when the test2 is the third `Context`.

Comment: Azure Logic App. started to support XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 for its Maps, i.e. XSLT transformations. There is no need to use XPath 1.0 anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//Context[Type = "test2"]/Value
```

will select all `Value` element children of `Context` elements of `Type` `test2`.